# python: How to construct a sparse matrix out of a 2D-image?

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have a 2D array which represents an image `(376, 450)`
How can I construct a new diagonal matrix (sparse matrix) which has all of the entries of the image along the diagonal and the rest zeroes? When I use for example `scipy.sparse.diags` I get following error:

```
ValueError: Different number of diagonals and offsets.
```

I already checked the documentation [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.diags.html) but for me, it is still not quite clear how to do that. Thanks a lot in advance for any tip!

Edit: If I just want to have the entries of the image (2D array) just in the zero-diagonal do I have to flatten the 2D array first into a single dimension?

That I have something like:

```
from scipy.sparse import diags

new_flat_array = [1,2,3,4, ...]
diags(new_flat_array, [0]).toarray()
```

But that way the resulting array will not be a sparse 2D matrix which I want.

Comment: How exactly did you use `sparse.diags`?  Don't expect us to guess as to what you did.

Comment: Please, spend some time reading ["How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and ["How to ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You will get better results by following the tips in those articles.